# Collapsible elements in android relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have a `RelativeLayout` parent with `ImageButton`s inside of it, arranged with `layout_below`, `layout_alignRight`, etc. This gives me the intended layout.

[image: this].

I would like to be able to collapse some of those buttons, so that the buttons that follow move one space "up". If I hide the visibility of one or more of the buttons with `gone`, the whole thing goes haywire, as they are laid out relative to each other. I can't resort to `GridView`, as I have to be able to run on API 7+.

So basically, I am looking for something like a CSS float thing. Is this achievable with `RelativeLayout` or are other layouts better?

Here's the layout (simplified):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?theme_background" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:background="?theme_header_background">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnAbout"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_about"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:text="App Name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="?theme_header_text"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnSetting"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="?theme_background"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imBtn1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imBtn2"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <View android:id="@+id/fakeView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imBtnAd" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fakeView1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn5"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fakeView1"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fakeView1"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <View android:id="@+id/fakeView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imBtnBiz" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn6"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fakeView2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn7"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fakeView2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fakeView2"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <View android:id="@+id/fakeView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imBtnAuto" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn8"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView3"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fakeView3"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn9"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fakeView3"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fakeView3"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            <View android:id="@+id/fakeView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imBtnHumor" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imBtn10"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#222"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fakeView4"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fakeView4"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Posting you xml may help. But there's a chance you gonna have to use nestead `LinearLayout`s in this one.

Comment: added layout to the question

Answer (score 1):

Probably you may select another strategy: do not try to hide buttons, but show only desired buttons instead. You may do this programatically like that:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if(showButtonB1) {
   Button b1 = new Button(this);
   //then set button image here
   layout.addView(b1);
  }

  if(showOtherButton){
  //...the same
  }

  //when all buttons needed were created:
  setContentView(layout);
}
```

Comment: will most likely go that way, was just looking for a "cleaner" solution. thanks for the input.